# How does framebuffer get updated in qemu running kvm/arm

Tags: linux, arm, framebuffer, qemu, kvm

I am running qemu-system-arm with kvm following this tutorial :

http://www.virtualopensystems.org/media/chromebook/chromebook.pdf

After reading some documentations (mostly blogs, lkml, and mailing list archives) and skim through codes (qemu, kvm, kernel), also, utilizing kernel trace function to trace kvm events, I can ascertain that vcpu thread runs guest code until hyp-trap occurs, and this is, mostly because of guest accessing mmio address for:
1. gpio access (I can't figure out what)
2. virtio-net, accessing ethernet 
3. serial access
the execution then goes back to kvm code to request userspace device emulation to qemu, and back again to guest.

My question is, for framebuffer, when does qemu have time to update the display (sdl)? if I am not mistaken, framebuffer memory range is within RAM itself, thus it is not MMIO. So, it does not interrupt cpu, nor it generates hyp-trap.

Comment: DMA can be configured for that ?

Comment: Like you said, it was DMA alright. QEMU updates the display via iothread, everytime the timer expired, it fires　gui_update() function which then calls framebuffer related stuff.